# Dynamically change filter property on object in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox, filter

Just give you an idea of what I am currently building. I have two images and a input slider:

```
input class="gwd-input-13xh" type="range" min="0" max="50" value="25" id="slider" oninput="getInput(this.value, this.max)">

.img_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px;
  left: 62px;
  top: 1px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: .8;
 }

.img_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 130px;
  left: 62px;
  top: 1px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  opacity: .8;
 }
```

Currently as you move the slider to the right it will change the properties(blur, opacity) on both images. Having one come into focus and opacity to 1 and the other fading out of focus and opacity to 0. Here is the code that performs said functions:

```
function getInput(value, max) {
  var img_1 = document.getElementById("img_1");
  var img_2 = document.getElementById("img_2");
  var sliderPercentage = (value / max).toFixed(2);
  img_1.style.opacity = 1 - sliderPercentage
  setBlur(img_1, (10 * sliderPercentage).toFixed(2));
  img_2.style.opacity = sliderPercentage;
  setBlur(img_2, 10 - (10 * sliderPercentage).toFixed(2));
 }

function setBlur(ele, value) {
  if (ele.style.hasOwnProperty('filter'))
    ele.style.filter = "blur(" + value + "px)";
  if (ele.style.hasOwnProperty('-webkit-filter'))
    ele.style["-webkit-filter"] = "blur(" + value + "px)";
  if (ele.style.hasOwnProperty('webkitFilter'))
    ele.style.webkitFilter = "blur(" + value + "px)";
  if (ele.style.hasOwnProperty('mozFilter'))
    ele.style.mozFilter = "blur(" + value + "px)";
  if (ele.style.hasOwnProperty('oFilter'))
    ele.style.oFilter = "blur(" + value + "px)";
  if (ele.style.hasOwnProperty('msFilter'))
    ele.style.msFilter = "blur(" + value + "px)";
}
```

This code does its job through and through. However, I am unable to adjust the filter when viewing the ad in `Firefox`. This is the error I am getting in the console:

```
mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
```

Any ideas on how I can tackle this current issue? I am not very familiar with creating things that function cross different browsers. Thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: That is not an error message, it's a warning (some code sets [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)?). Also, it looks like the posted snippet wouldn't have anything to do with this warning message. Maybe a library you're using causes it?

Comment: @Teemu Thanks to your question on `what is setBlur doing` i was able to figure out the answer. Thanks you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was the order in which the conditional statements were presented on my `setBlur` function. Once I moved the `mozFilter` condition up, it was able to run the function fine. I'm thinking this is because it found those properties but in `Firefox` you cannot change those, you have to change `-moz-filter`.